# Any formula or estimates the Green function for the Laplacian in $3D$ periodic box?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, green-function

Let $\mathbb{T}^3=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3$ be the three-dimensional torus with sides identified. That is, I am considering the unit box $[0,1]^3$ with periodic boundary conditions.

In this case, I am (hopefully) trying to find an explicit formula for the Green function for the Laplacian $-\Delta$.

That is, what would a function $G$ on $\mathbb{T}^3$ satisfying $-\Delta G(x)=\delta^3(x)$ look like explicitly?

I am aware that on whole $\mathbb{R}^3$, $G(x)=  \frac{1}{4\pi \lvert x \rvert}$.

According to standard PDE references, I think I need to find the corrector function $\phi^y(x)$ defined by
\begin{equation}
-\Delta_x \phi^y(x)=0 \text{ for } x \in (0,1)^3 \text{ and } \phi^y(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi \lvert x-y \rvert} \text{ for } x \in \partial \mathbb{T}^3
\end{equation}
together with $y \in \mathbb{T}^3$ and $y \neq x$.

However, I have great difficulty solving the above Poisson equation, and moreover, I am not sure if the resulting $\phi^y(x)$ will even be a periodic function.

Could anyone please help me?

Edit: I forgot the fact that the periodic boundary conditions allow zero modes and the Laplacian does not have an inverse under this condition. So, I am restricting the domain of the Laplacian to $L^2$ space over $\mathbb{T}^3$ with no zero modes. Then will it make a difference?

Comment: With periodic boundary conditions, the Laplacian has zero modes, and therefore it doesn't have an inverse. Perhaps the application you have in mind can make use of a pseudo-inverse ...

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt sorry for not specifying further conditions. I am restricting the domain to the space of functions without zero mode. Will it make a difference?

Comment: What is the intention with this Green;s function? If you had a use case maybe the original problem you were going to use the Green's function for is more tractable through another means?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Ok, I have provided more context in which this question has come out: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450778/validity-of-formula-ux-frac14-pi-int-g-nabla-y-frac1-lvert-x-y-rve I would deeply appreciate if you help me.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Could you also help me with the above link?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt  I would deeply appreciate if you help me with [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461100/is-the-leray-projection-continuous-with-respect-to-the-frechet-topology-of-smooth) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it depends on what you mean by "explicit". Let $(\varphi_k)_k \subset L^2(\mathbb{S}^1)$ be the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $\mathbb{S}^1$, these have an explicit form that comes by solving the relative ODE, and let $(\lambda_k)_k$ be the relative eigenvalues. Then $G_{\mathbb{S}^1}(p,q)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\varphi_k(p)\varphi_k(q)}{\lambda_k} $ and I highly doubt this has a form more explicit that this, meaning some form that does not involve an infinite sum or other similar operations. Since $\mathbb{T^3}=\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1 $ you can write the Green function of $\mathbb{T}^3$ as a (triple) sum involving only the eigenfunctions $(\varphi_k)_k$ and eigenvalues $(\lambda_k)_k$, I don't think there is a form more explicit that this sum.

Comment: In one dimension, the sum can be carried out, yielding a quite simple form for the Green's function. In higher dimensions, it becomes more complicated.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I didn't know that you can find a closed form in one dimension, thank you for pointing out. Where can I find this explicit form?

Comment: If you'll allow me to redefine the interval to be $[-\pi ,\pi]$, $G(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2} |x-y| + \frac{1}{4\pi } (x-y)^2 + \frac{\pi}{6} $.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I am a bit confused by your formula, this does not even satisfy $G(x+2\pi,y)=G(x,y)$. How can this be the Green function on $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: This is a very beautiful result, i'm not too familiar with green's function so forgive me if this is trivial but is it true in general that a green's function of an operator $O$ over a bounded manifold $M$ can be written as a sum over the eigenfunctions+eigenvalues of said operator over the manifold?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal sure this is always true. In the sense of distributions take the formula $u=\sum_{k\ge 1} \langle u, \varphi_k \rangle_{L^2(M)} \varphi_k$ and put $u=G(x,p)$ for fixed $p\in M$. Use the definition of eigenfunction and integrate by parts to get the Laplacian hit the Green function, you get the formula I have written for any compact manifold.

Comment: @mcaselli - this is the form of the Green's function for $x,y\in [-\pi ,\pi]$. If you wish to take $x$ or $y$ outside the interval, the function is simply defined by periodicity. You can convince yourself that $G$ is well-behaved at the boundaries.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal - this is simply what is known as the spectral representation of the Green's function.