# Is the Leray projection continuous with respect to the Frechet topology of smooth periodic vector fields in $3$ dimensions?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $\mathbb{T}^3:=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3$ be the $3$-torus and $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ be the Frechet space of smooth periodic vector fields on $\mathbb{T}^3$.

By Helmholtz decomposition (or Hodge's Theorem), each $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ is uniquely written as
\begin{equation}
f(x)=a+g(x)+h(x)
\end{equation}
where $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a constant vector while $g, h \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ satisfy

1. $\int_{\mathbb{T}^3}g=\int_{\mathbb{T}^3}h=0$
2. $\nabla \times g = 0$, that is $g$ is curl-free
3. $\nabla \cdot h=0$, that is $h$ is divergence-free

Now, the Leray projection $\mathbb{P}$ is a linear map on $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}f= h
\end{equation}

Now, I wonder if this $\mathbb{P}$ is continuous with respect to the Frechet topology of $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$. I am concerned with this issue because the seminorms on $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ contain supremums, and usual Fourier expansion is not (equi-)continuous with respect to $L^\infty$-norm..

Could anyone pleaes clarify for me?

Comment: Yes it is. It is enough to look at the operator $f \mapsto \mathrm{grad}(\triangle^{-1}(\mathrm{div}(f)))$. This operator maps the Sobolev space $H^k$ to itself boundedly. You have that $C^k$ embeds continuously in $H^k$, and $H^k$ embeds into $C^{k-2}$ by Sobolev embedding. So this shows that if $f_j\to f$ in $C^{k}$ you have $\mathbb{P} f_j \to f$ in $C^{k-2}$.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you. I guess $k \geq 2$ here?

Comment: For the boundedness of the Leray projection on $H^k$, you don't need $k \geq 2$. But for the second part, you want $k \geq 2$ to ensure $k - 2 \geq 0$. Of course, you actually want $k$ to be arbitrarily large to prove that $\mathbb{P} f_j \to f$ in all of the seminorms generating the topology of $C^\infty$.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you. Just one thing : do you mean $\mathbb{P}f_j \to \mathbb{P}f$ for $f_j \to f$?

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you. Could you perhaps help me resolve the following confusion [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461365/extreme-confusion-over-the-tautology-of-the-solution-for-pdes)?