# Extreme confusion over the tautology of the solution for PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $u_0 : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth divergence free vector field. Then, it is well-known from the theory of Navier-Stokes equation that there exists some $T \in (0,\infty]$ and a smooth time-dependent vector field $U: \mathbb{R}^3 \times [0,T)  \to \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying the incompressible NS equation with the initial data $u_0$:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t U- \Delta U + \mathbb{P}_{LH} \Bigl[(U \cdot \nabla)U\Bigr]=0 \text{ and } U(x,t=0)=u_0(x) \text{ and } \nabla_x\cdot U=0
\end{equation}

Now, consider the following inhomogeneous heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^3 \times [0,T)$:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t V - \Delta V=-\mathbb{P}_{LH} \Bigl[(U \cdot \nabla)U\Bigr] \text{ and } V(x,t=0)=u_0(x)
\end{equation}
which we intend to solve for $V$.

Then, by uniqueness of the weak solution for the inhomogeneous heat equation, we must have $V=U$.

Here, some very subtle but annoying confusion arises:
\begin{equation}
V \text{ is intended as a solution of the inhomogeneous heat equation. } 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{However, it is apparent that } V=U \text{, which solves the Naiver-Stokes equation}...
\end{equation}

How should I make sense of such a blatantly parodoxical phenomenon? I am utterly confused about the situation here. Could anyone please clarify for me?

Comment: What is the paradox? You can solve $e^x = 1$ and find $x = 0$, and you can solve $y^2 = 0$ and find $y = 0$. The two have the same value and "solve different equations".

Comment: In fact, a bit part of the power of the analysis of linear inhomogeneous PDEs with variable coefficients lies in the fact that every solution to a nonlinear PDE is a solution to a linear, possibly inhomogeneous PDE with variable coefficients, where the inhomogeneity and coefficients are determined by the solution. "Freezing" coefficients like this is how you apply ideas like maximal principle to nonlinear equations.

Comment: @WillieWong OK, then is the above $V$ the solution of the two equations "simultaneously"?

Comment: @WillieWong Is it still correct to say that $V$ solves the given inhomogeneous heat equation?

Comment: Yes. One of the standard ways to prove the existence of a solution to Navier Stokes is by doing an iteration where each step you solve an inhomoveneous heat equation $\partial_t U_n - \Delta U_n = -(U_{n-1}\cdot \nabla)U_{n-1} - \nabla P_{n-1}$ and hope that $U_n$ converges. If it does, then the limiting function solves Navier Stokes.

Comment: Ehem. $\partial_t U-\Delta U+(U\cdot\nabla)U=0$ is NOT the incompressible Navier-Stokes equation. There is another term called the pressure.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy oops.. I forgot the Leray projection. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I just corrected my question.

Comment: @WillieWong your $U_n$ seems different form the standard Galerkin approximation $u_n$ that satisfies $\partial_t u_n - \Delta u_n = -\mathbb{P}_{LH} \Bigl[(u_n \cdot \nabla ) u_n \Bigr]$. Could you perhaps explain more about the construction using $U_n$?

Comment: @WillieWong Or any reference is appreciated as well!

Comment: See Chapter 4 (I think; I don't have my copy with me so am not 100% sure of the chapter numbers) of Lemarie-Rieusset's _The Navier-Stokes Problem in the 21st Century_; alternatively the scheme is described in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physd.2008.03.010

Comment: @WillieWong I am always grateful for your help. Could you please help me with the following issue as well? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462093/absolute-continuity-of-t-to-lvert-ut-rvert2-h-and-gelfand-triple-are